# How to Create custom App URL schemes for IOS using phonegap build?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, url-scheme

**I was searching for this problem since long time.finally i got the key answer.**

Answer (score 0):

**How to create AppURL scheme for your own app.Here is the answer.**

Simply use the following plugins into config.xml

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme">
       <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="YourAppName" />
   </plugin>
```

**How to Get URL Scheme of any app?**

-Right click on a app in iTunes, 'Show in Finder'

-Duplicate the app to Desktop

-Change .ipa to .zip

-Unzip and open the Payload folder

-Right click on app, 'Show Package Contents'

-Open 'Info.plist' in a text editor app like TextWrangler

-Search 'CFBundleURLSchemes'

-Between the  tag you can find the URL